# Nodejs random query

Tags: ajax, node.js, postgresql, express

I'm trying to get a random item from my local database using ajax.The first time i do a ajax request i get a random item afterwards every ajax request return the same item.

```
 var express = require('express')
var app = express();
var customers = require('./module');
var pg = require('pg');
var conString = "postgres://postgres:pass@localhost/test";
var client = new pg.Client(conString);



app.get('/res', function(req, res) {


client.connect(function(err) {
          if(err) {
            return console.error('could not connect to postgres', err);
          }
          client.query('SELECT * FROM t_items OFFSET random()*300 LIMIT 1', function(err, result) {
            if(err) {
              return console.error('error running query', err);
            }
            console.log(result.rows[0]);

              res.contentType('json');
              res.send({ some: result.rows[0] });


             client.end();
          });
    });
});


app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000))
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))

app.get('/',function(req, res){


    res.render("index");
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log("Node app is running at localhost:" + app.get('port'))
})
```

If I try to wrap it in app.post('/req' )....
i get could not connect to postgres [Error: Connection terminated]
I've tried with client pooling but still the same problem

Comment: Don't end the connection yourself. It will timeout by itself without ending it. So try removing client.end() and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just move your query inside function app.get('/res', function(req, res)

This happening because db query is executed only once. To prevent it - move your code inside /res route, and it will be executed every request.